# Prevent HTMLAgilityPack from connecting words when using InnerText

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to do a simple task of getting text from HTML document.
So I'm using HTMLdoc.DocumentNode.InnerText for that.
The problem is that on some sites the don't put spaces between words when they are in a different tags. In those cases the DocumentNode.InnerText connect those word into one and it became useless.

for example, I'm trying to read a site contain that line

```
<span>İstanbul</span><ul><li><a href="i1.htm">Adana</a></li>
```

I'm  getting  "İstanbulAdana" which is meaningless.

I couldn't find any solution at HTMLAgilityPack documentation nor Google

Do I missing something?

Thanks,

Comment: That is the expected behavior. Tried looping through the node tree building the text manually?

Comment: That's exactly what should happen. You could insert a space between each node manually inside of a loop whilst building your strings.

Comment: I believe it might work, 
But is it really the only solution for that? 
moreover, It's not so simple to write that since some tags contains text and another tags.
but InnerText is recursive, so I cant get just the text within specific tag and not in it's child

Comment: If you're using InnerText and selecting the nodes correctly then it shouldn't be returning any HTML (tags)? Then using the method described above would work. Or you could check inside your loop whether the nodes 'InnerText' contains a tag and if it does, get the inner text of that instead and then add to your list of strings...

Comment: InnerText will give me also the text of its descendants.
Can't see how I can use it in that loop you're suggesting

Comment: Can you post the source document you're using so I can give this a try?

Comment: http://www.internethaber.com/gazetecilere-yalvardi-yakardi-sildiremedi-foto-galerisi-24214-p4.htm


also, take a look on this example:
<div>My dogs are<ul><li>Albert</li><li>Issac</li></ul></div>

Comment: `InnerText will give me also the text of its descendants` It wont if you're selecting the node correctly. From that `<div>` tag, what values are you wanting to extract?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That should be rather easy to do.

```
const string html = @"<span>İstanbul</span><ul><li><a href=""i1.htm"">Adana</a></li>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
string result = string.Join(" ", doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
  .Where(n => !n.HasChildNodes && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n.InnerText))
  .Select(n => n.InnerText));
Console.WriteLine(result); // prints "İstanbul Adana"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code snippet hangs for this example:

```
const string html = @"<td><font size=""2"">abc </font><font size=""2"">(</font><font size=""2"">abc</font><font size=""2"">) </font><a href=""?query=abc"">abc</a>, abc<br><font size=""2"">abc </font>abc, <a href=""?query=abc"">abc</a>, abc, <a href=""?query=abc"">abc</a><br><font size=""2"">abc </font>abc abc, abc abc<br></td>";
```

It doesn't hang without the join-clause (but it doesn't put spaces correctly neither).